# Semantic UI search dropdown with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to create a search dropdown using Semantic UI and AngularJS to bind the data.
If I put the data statically, it works fine:

```
<select class="ui search dropdown">
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

[image]

If I try to use the `ng-repeat` attribute inside `<option>` tag, it appears like that below: the data doesn't appear like a dropdown.

```
<select class="ui search dropdown" data-ng-model="selectedGender">
    <option data-ng-repeat="gender in genders" value="{{gender.Id}}">{{gender.Text}}</option>
</select>
```

[image]

And if I try to use the `data-ng-options` attribute, even the dropdown caret doesn't appear!

```
<select class="ui search dropdown" data-ng-model="selectedGender"
    data-ng-options="gender.Id as gender.Text for gender in genders"></select>
```

[image]

What can I do to solve this? Do you guys already have this problem? Thanks for all answers!

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your last example (which is the correct way to do it by the way). http://plnkr.co/edit/UCfdrQ0l9CuRdzKXwhGE?p=preview Are you able to create an example that shows the issue?

Comment: @Matthew, the problem is not with the dropdown, but with the way that Semantic UI renderizes the element, you know? I'll create a live example about

Comment: perpahs adding a track by like this `data-ng-options="gender.Id as gender.Text for gender in genders track by gender.Id ">` gets the job done... try it

Answer (score 2):

Hi I use Semantic dropdown this way

```
     <div class="field">
        <label for="Role">Role</label>
        <div class="ui selection dropdown">
            <div class="default text">{{user.role}}</div>
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="menu">
                <div ng-repeat="role in userRoles" class="item" ng-click="setRole(role.title)">{{role.title}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**but** I add a `ng-click` directive in my class item to **get the selected item**.

In the controller, you will find

```
$scope.setRole = function (role) {
   $scope.user.role = role;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive('dropdown', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        scope: { ngModel: '=' },
        link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $(elm).dropdown();
                $('input', elm).on('change', function () {
                    scope.ngModel = $(this).val();
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

```
<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown" ng-model="data.dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" />
    <div class="default text">Please Select</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="option-1">Option 1</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="option-2">Option 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```